# How to send pdf file as base64data url in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

i am using angular 2.i wish to convert pdf file to base64dataurl. i tried following

```
<input type="file" (change)="fileChange($event)" placeholder="Upload file" accept=".pdf,.doc,.docx">-->
      <!--<p>Select a File to Load:</p>
<input id="inputFileToLoad" type="file" onchange="loadImageFileAsURL()" />
```

my ts file is

```
fileChange(event) {
   var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsBinaryString(event)
   reader.onload = function () {
     console.log(reader.result);
   };
   reader.onerror = function (error) {
     console.log('Error: ', error);
   };
}
```

i tried the following js fiddle 
[http://jsfiddle.net/eliseosoto/JHQnk/][1]

please prefer the code which is execute in angular 2(version 2.4).

Answer (score 0):

Attached working plunkr on angular 2 based on ur JSFiddle

https://plnkr.co/edit/PFfebmnqH0eQR9I92v0G?p=preview

all logic is in app.component.ts

on reader.onload, the context gets changed,
Hence i wrote logic in sepearate function & binded it using

```
  reader.onload =this._handleReaderLoaded.bind(this);
```

Comment: thanks.bro it is working..2) do you have any seed project which support nodejs and angular 2.

Comment: You are welcomed :)
You can upvote it & mark as answer if it helped :p

Comment: bro i voted also but i am getting  " vote caste less than 15 reputation recorded but do not change publicity displayed"..

Comment: yes, because ur repuation is less than 16, u can accept this as ur answer :D